# Android webview throwing reference errors while loading html, javascript source from assets

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am trying to adapt a web application into android webview by `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content_to_Change/dev/index.html").`

I have pasted whole application code into assets folder as `'assets/Content_To_Change/dev'.` When I run the android app, index page is loaded fine, but after that execution halts here and there in predictive manner with reference errors like below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined at file:///android_asset/Content_To_Change/dev/activity/views/screen4/screen.js:361

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yPoint' of null at file:///android_asset/Content_To_Change/dev/activity/views/screen4/screen.js:394
```

Also these errors sometimes occur at one place and sometimes at other. I am wondering why there reference errors popping up while the app is working without any errors in safari(iOS) and desktop browsers!

After doing some more hit and trials, it seems there is some sort of load order mismatch in rendering of js/css ? I also tried with android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest but to no avail...:(

Here is my Code:

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/Content_To_Change/dev/index.html";
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
    // webView.setInitialScale(WEBVIEW_SCALE);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); //

    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.enableSmoothTransition();
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    //      settings.set
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

    settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // forces it to
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Menifest has this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please advise what should I do in order to run my web app seamlessly in webview ?.

Comment: Those look like they are JavaScript errors.  Could you please post index.html?

Comment: Actually, screen.js looks like the file in which the error is occurring.

Comment: Thanks EJK for prompt response!. Actually this is a huge code and as i said everything works fine when i open same index.html in iOS safari webview or any desktop browser. index.html is fine and loads js and css to load my first page. I can't paste it here due to its too long. problems occur only after that when there more complex js calls are made within the js files.

Comment: but same screen.js works fine in other browser. its looking looking like rendering issue of webkit which is causing some sort of delay in loading js etc, but not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: The error message "Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined at.." is a classic JavaScript error.  It means that a JavaScript object reference is null (undefined) and yet the code is attempting to reference the 'identifier' property of the null object.

Comment: So in order to debug this, the JavaScript needs to be analyzed.  Based on your observations, it just may work out to be a iOS/Android web view issue.  However the problem almost certainly does not lie in the Java code you have posted.

Comment: Try to set target >= 17 in your AndroidManifest (this will force to use the newest WebView implementation) and check if it works.

Comment: @bonnyz, thanks but target is already 21 so that should not be an issue.
After doing some observation i am seeing MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) when html code encounters video tags. Looks like this error breaks rest of the operations and js loads which consequently throws reference errors. Any idea ?